# How to get a key with periods/full stops in a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, naming-conventions, aws-iot

New to SQL. I'm trying to implement an AWS rule in SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM '$aws/things/RaspberryPi/shadow/update/accepted' 
WHERE state.reported.moisture < 400
```

but I get the value from a json like this where I can't alter the keys:

```
{
  "reported": {
    "Q..1:3-1": "01",
    "AI..4:1-1": "00F3",
    "AI..4:3-1": "019E",
    "AI..4:5-1": "00C7"
  }
}
```

So 'state.reported.*moisture*' needs to be replaced by state.reported.*AI..4:5-1*.

I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM '$aws/things/RaspberryPi/shadow/update/accepted' 
WHERE state.reported.'AI..4:5-1' < 400
```

only this doesn't work.

How can I insert this a key like this in this SQL statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database specifically?

Comment: it is in Amazon Web Services following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-moisture-create-rule.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the get command like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM '$aws/things/logo_temp/shadow/update' 
WHERE get(get(state,"reported"),"Q..1:3-1") = "01"
```